# SQL select Count a Column with distinct other column

Tags: select, count

I have a table follow this:

```
Ord_no | Share_no
   1      1160
   1      1160
   2      1170
   3      1160
   3      1170
```

I want to count of difference of `Ord_no` with same `Share_no` record.
for example :

```
Count Share_no=1160 ~~> 2 
Count Share_no=1170 ~~> 2
```

I use C# .net 
and want to pass 1160 record ,to database with a stored procedure and give '2' as a query result.

"select count(*), share_no from ord_tbl where share_no=@share_no group by share_no"

Comment: how `Share_no=1160 ~~> 2` is it can be either 3 or 4 in my understanding

Comment: thank's alot Grijesh dear,

1160 once by ord_no 1 and 3
1170 once by ord_no 2 and 3

Answer (score 1):

I assume you table name **test** and the answer should be :

```
select count(*), share_no from test group by share_no;
```